# Junit Testwatcher skipped/ignored test

Tags: java, junit, watch

I created a `TestWatcher` which should do something when a `TestCase` `fails`, `succeeded`or is `skipped`.

The `Methods` `succeeded`and `failed` are fired, but neither

```
@Override
protected void skipped(AssumptionViolatedException e, Description description) {
    System.out.println("Skipped: " + description);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

nor

```
@Override
protected void skipped(org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException e, Description description)
{
    System.out.println("Skippedinternal: " + description);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

are fired.

Why aren't those two called when a `test`is `ignored` or is this the wrong way to react to an `ignored test` and if that's the case how can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The skipped event in TestWatcher (http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) is triggered only in case the test is skipped due to failed assumption (http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html).